# Firefox - how can I open multiple sessions(profiles) in different tabs?

Tags: cookies, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I'm looking for a solution to open multiple profiles in different tabs in Mozilla Firefox.

However there's a catch: I want profiles to be switched automatically. For example, when I click on the first tab, the first profile is activated; when I click on second, the second profile is activated, etc.

I know this can be done by swapping cookies into different 'session' files. I've tried Firefox extensions like Cookiepie, Multifox and Cookieswap - the last one did the job, but not completely; I still have to manually do the 'profile change' by clicking the Cookieswap icon in the bottom-right corner and selecting the required profile.

How can I simply bypass it, so that when I click a certain tab it loads the specified profile?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a way. Each profile is a unique instance of Firefox. Tabs are pages grouped in one instance.  Each profile is in a different process, and has its own top-level window. They do not yet provide the functionality of placing a tab from one instance into the window of another instance.

Comment: Regards Keith, thanks for your effort. To be precise, the 'unique instance' is not what i am actually looking for. Sorry if you misunderstood me (written lapsus :) ), but multiple profiles here refer to profiles within Cookieswap (mozilla plugin/addon). So actually i will login to Firefox with one 'Firefox profile'. Alright? I simply want to know how to change mentioned 'Cookieswap profiles' without any extra clicking (except when user changes Firefox tabs). It should be easy :/